# How to test the statistical significance of probabilities?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance

I am working on a model with as output a list of probabilities. If I have two lists of such probabilities, how can I test if the difference between the two lists is large?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please elaborate about what these probability values are? Also, what do you mean when you want to know if the differences are statistically significant?

Comment: The question is clear but it looks misguided, because "statistical significance" is not a relevant concept.  You have two sets of probabilities, each created using some kind of simulation.  There are no data, no sampling, no model for how the probabilities might vary from one simulation to the next.  There's nothing one can say.

Comment: What type of simulation are you talking about? Does it have a random component? Montecarlo simulation, where the probabilities mentioned are frequencies of an event across simulation samples?

Comment: If so, then see https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Statistics/Mostly_Harmless_Statistics_(Webb)/09%3A_Hypothesis_Tests_and_Confidence_Intervals_for_Two_Populations/9.03%3A_Two_Proportion_Z-Test_and_Confidence_Interval

Comment: It sounds like you need to study how the output varies (a) when a particular simulation is repeated and (b) when a simulation is lengthened.

Comment: Normally it helps if you describe the actual problem you are solving rather than trying to abstract it. If possible please describe what these probabilities are and what model is being used.

Comment: If you repeat your work, can the numbers change?

Comment: The example is difficult to fathom, because those "probabilities" do not sum to unity.  They appear merely to be numbers between $0$ and $1.$

Comment: So then why does the parameter change?

Comment: This looks like "Sensitivity Analysis" to me. You can find many-resources on line.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos are there resources on probabilities as well?

Comment: @Seb I am not sure what you mean. In your case the probabilities are the outcome of the model, so the techniques of the sensitivity analysis would be the same.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have a bit of a misconception about what statistical significance actually means. Statistical significance only makes sense if you have data from a sample/samples where you don't know the original population/populations. In this context, statistical significance gives an estimate about the parameters of the original population/populations.

So, when you say, for example with a t-test, that the difference between two sample means is statistically significant, you are actually saying you have found evidence that there are differences between the means of the original populations.

In your case, you have obtained probabilities from a simulation/experiment. This is a completely different scenario. So, statistical significance in this case doesn't make any sense.

Comment: How can I then test if both set of probabilities are different from each other?

Comment: You compare them the way you would compare any two vectors.

Comment: How do you mean? You can calculate the difference between two vectors that is true but how can I say something if that difference is large or not?

Comment: @Seb How would you say in a t-test?

Comment: At the end, even in a statistical test, the threshold is set arbitrarily. Why should alpha be, say, 0.05 or 0.01? Just because we have agreed upon it. There is no reason for a hard threshold set there. In your case, you might not have a convention like that to help you with your conclusions, but at the end, you can use a lot of different methods: graphical methods, summary statistics, etc. Depending on the data you have, one method will suit you better than others. Also, knowledge and context on the data and the topic of research will for sure help you.

Comment: @Seb The point of hypothesis testing is to show that the observed difference is not just a fluke of the sampling (what you happened to observe). If there is no variability in the probabilities you would get, there is nothing to test; the probabilities either are the same or they are different. Hypothesis testing does not tell you if a difference should matter to you, which is the domain of *practical* significance instead of statistical significance. (Many people look to statistical significance to tell them if a difference is important. This is an error.)

Comment: @Dave I am not really familiar with practical significance. Are there also some 'formal' tests that you can apply or is it more about observing the results and logical thinking?

Comment: @Seb Practical significance is not what tests are about. Practical significance is about what matters, which is for the subject matter experts to judge. (I can think of ways for statisticians to augment that knowledge, such as simulations or phrasing differences in meaningful terms, but this is, ultimately, a call by the subject matter experts, many of whom will (mistakenly) think that's what a p-value tells them. You should expect to have this argument in your career.)